# C++, with vector<int[2]> can I push_back({someNum1,someNum2})?

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

I have the vector:

```
vector<int[2]> storeInventory; //storeInventory[INDEX#]{ITEMNUM, QUANTITY}
```

and I am wanting to use the `push_back()` method to add new arrays to the inventory vector. Something similar to this:

```
const int ORANGE = 100001;
const int GRAPE = 100002

storeInventory.push_back({GRAPE,24});
storeInventory.push_back{ORANGE, 30};
```

However, when I try using the syntax as I have above I get the error `Error: excpeted an expression`. Is what I am trying just not possible, or am I just going about it the wrong way?

Comment: use std::pair instead of the array or use std::map

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Built-in arrays are not *Assignable* or *CopyConstructible*. This violates container element requirements (at least for C++03 and earlier). In other words, you can't have `std::vector` of `int[2]` elements. You have to wrap your array type to satisfy the above requirements.

As it has already been suggested, `std::array` in a perfect candidate for a wrapper type in C++11. Or you can just do

```
struct Int2 {
  int a[2];
};
```

and use `std::vector<Int2>`.

Comment: Technically, I think `vector<int[2]> storeInventory;` is valid in C++11 with the new fine-grained container requirements.  The value type needs only be _destructible_, which an array type is.  `push_back` requires that the value type is copy insertable, which an array type is not.  A container of an array type is not very usable (or useful), and using a wrapper structure (like `std::array<T, N>`) would be advisable.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe it's possible to pass arrays like that. Consider using `std::array` instead:

```
vector<std::array<int, 2> > storeInventory; 
storeInventory.push_back({{GRAPE,24}});
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's only vector of int[2] you could use:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> vec
```

Adding elements:

```
int a, b;
vec.push_back(std::make_pair(a, b));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
storeInventory.push_back({GRAPE, 24});
storeInventory.push_back({ORANGE, 30});
```

You can try this. I think you forgot parentheses.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, which is why I am asking this question.

Answer (score 2):

C-style arrays are not copyable, so can't be used as the element type in a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a `std::vector<int *>` :)

Comment: This answer could be improved if it made more of an effort to explain to the asker why this solution would work and how they should apply it.